# ¿Como puedo obtener el home path de un usuario en especifico en linux sin que influya el como se ejecute el script (sudo o sin sudo)?

Tags: python, linux

tengo un problema que no he podido resolver. Estoy atorado en un pequeño fragmento de código de mi proyecto, estoy realizando una función en python en donde verifica si existe o no un archivo con el modulo de os.path.isfile, este archivo se almacena en el home path de cada usuario, el problema esta en que mi herramienta necesita ejecutarse afuerza con sudo para que funcione, sino da acceso denegado en varias cosas, así que cuando llega el momento en el que verifica la existencia del archivo, la variable home (utilizo el modulo os.path.expanduser) cambia a /root, y yo no necesito la de root, yo necesito la que es tipo /home/user/. He realizado un script de prueba para mostrarles la salida que genera al utilizar el os.path.expanduser con sudo y sin sudo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo hacer que genere la misma salida de  `/home/kali`  al ejecutarlo con sudo??

Espero sus respuestas y gracias.

Comment: `sudo -u kali python h.py` ?

Comment: En ese caso tendría que obtener el nombre de usuario de los que ejecuten el script, como podría obtenerlo si el script se ejecuta con sudo? para que no obtenga root, sino volvería al mismo escenario problemático.

Comment: aquí hay pistas para bash https://stackoverflow.com/q/3522341/1423096 habría que verlo en python

Comment: Muchas gracias le echaré un vistazo a la información

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fijate si te funciona una combinación de [Identify user in a Bash script called by sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3522393/1423096) y de [How to get sudo username in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43929714/1423096)

```
$ sudo python
[sudo] password for development:
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr  9 2019, 04:50:39)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import pwd
>>> pwd.getpwuid(os.geteuid()).pw_name
'root'
>>> os.getenv("SUDO_USER")
'development'
>>> exit()
```